# Can't place two buttons in NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem

In my project, I need to add two `UIBarButtonItem`s to a `NavigationItem` of a view controller. I solved this with this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem saveButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Save", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, (sender, e) => {
    //some saving code...
    });
    UIBarButtonItem delButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Delete", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, (sender, e) => {
    //some deletion code...
    });
    UIBarButtonItem[] items = new UIBarButtonItem[]
    {
        saveButton,
        delButton
    };
    this.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems = items;
```

It worked in previous versions of MonoTouch (on iOS 5, both device and simulator), but (I think so) after I upgraded to MonoTouch 6, only first button from the array is displayed.
I try to use `NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItems(items, false)` method, but without any effect.

Is it a common problem or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a common problem or I am doing something wrong?

Touch.Unit, MonoTouch's unit test runner, use `RightBarButtonItems` and works correctly (showing both buttons) with MonoTouch 6.0.x.

OTOH I see nothing wrong in your code snippet (but it's a short one). Your best bet is to create a small, self contained, application that shows your issue and attach it to a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com). We'll be able to review it and see what's wrong (or you might find the issue yourself, if it's inside your own code, when doing the test case).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I've wrote a sample application and found out what was the reason. I'l make a separate answer to describe the case.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the case. The situation described in my question happens when you already have a back button and a some custom view (i.e. `UISegmentedControl` instance) in a `navigationItem.TitleView`. In this case, when you set `navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems` with an array of `UIBarButtonItems` and the space is not enough to display a `navigationItem.TitleView` and both right buttons, iOS renders only the first button of the array and discard the other.
I verified this in a native ObjC application and got the same behavior.